# Constant dump current and OVP simplest

Tags: bjt, constant-current

I'm on the hunt for a circuit which is simply to dump 3A (+/- 0.5A) cc to ground if it receives a signal from an Arduino or if the voltage exceeds 5.5 V on the load it should clamp it for up to 5A (+/- 0.5A) to prevent capacitor breakdown at 7V. The powersourse the charger uses is a high precision bench powersupply whith cc set to 3.7V 3.3A. It's to be used to discharge a 500mF 5V super capacitor for safety reasons (I can't allow a charged cap to leave the production test) and prevent over charging if malfunction of charger. It's part of a production test and this part is for the capacitor.

My current plan is to use an NPN BJT to dump the charge and use a resistor in series with the Arduino input signal to set the voltage. But I can't figure out how to use a Zener diode or similar to automatically trigger the constant current circuit without the need of many components.

Comment: Is that dump to 0V or is there a lower setpoint for cutoff or do you really want an SCR crowbar to a polyfuse.

Comment: The 'dump' is a bit melodramatic and certainly confusing. You can dump charge, you're talking about current. I think you mean crowbar or short circuit. Please can you edit your question to show an actual circuit diagram with the power supply and load and so on. The more detail, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you I have added context. I don't  know the circuit and there for its hard to draw.

Comment: Johan . Not enough. You need to define your power source better and setpoint.  It is better to use series LDO than a shunt dump method.

Comment: how much precision do you need? what output voltage range?

Comment: Thank you for the help with asking the right question. It helps me learn how to Beyer formulate them in the future also. The question is now updated.

Comment: Tony and Tony did you have any tip based on my updates?